# How can I set OnCompletionListener to earlier time?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to loop a MediaPlayer.seekTo() call to repeat a section of a song indefinitely.

I am currently able to achieve this once by using a countdown timer like this:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable) {
    public void run() {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(startTime);
    }
}, endTime - startTime);
```

However, simply putting a loop around that results in the app hanging. Instead of using a loop, I thought I might be able to make this work by using the OnCompletionListener to call seekTo() again. Is it possible to have the OnCompletionListener run upon reaching my endTime variable rather than the actual end of the song?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by, instead of using a Handler with the postDelayed  endTime - startTime, simply starting the second thread and having it perform the loop inside of the run() function. Inside of that loop, I check if the current position == endTime and if it does, it calls seekTo(startTime).